# sequelize.js, count number of associated items

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to get only the count of associated items. This does what you'd expect:

```
var options = { 
  where: { 
    username: { like: '%' + q + '%'}}, 
    include: [Transaction]
  }};

User.findAll(options).success(function (users) {
  res.json(users);
});
```

But to get the count right now I'm having to iterate over each of the users, taking a count of the transactions, grabbing the dataValues, and manually amending a new property (transactionCount) to the dataValues object.

I feel like there should be a much cleaner way of doing this (maybe using pseudo properties?) but the answer is eluding me. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
var options = { 
  where: { 
    username: { like: '%' + q + '%'}}, 
    include: [Transaction]
  }};

User.findandCountAll(options).success(function (users) {
  res.json(users);
});
```

Details here: http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-finders

Comment: Thanks for the reply. findAndCountAll returns a count of the Users, but does not contain a tally for the associated Transactions. Each user may potentially have hundreds of associated Transactions, so it's important to transmit only the count for each user, not all the Transactions data.

Comment: You'll need to drop down to pure SQL for that.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have SQL in place now. Could you offer any advice in updating the model by using setter methods? I [tried the approach as per the docs](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-getters---setters) but the properties don't appear in the dataValues list.

Comment: I'd suggest 1) answering your own question with the SQL you used and 2) creating a new question with the getter/setter you're trying to use to count the associations, and what is being returned.

Answer (score -2):

In the case of having only one Associated model, I was able to iterate over each user, count the associated Transactions, and then copy the User data values into a separate array and send that on to the client.

```
var values = [],
    i;

 for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var user = users[i],
      userValues = users[i].dataValues;
   if (userValues.hasOwnProperty('username')) {
    userValues.transactions = (!!user.transactions) ? user.transactions.length : 0;
    values.push(userValues);
  }
}
```

In the case of needing counts on two Associated models, I ended up using raw SQL to get the counts for Transactions and Accounts. I then use something much like above to manually add the values to the base model. *Note*: You need to rename the fields in the query, otherwise Sequelize will interpret the period (.) in an unfriendly way and assign properties with names like `COUNT(T` and `id)`.

```
var query = 'SELECT A.id AS id, ' +
  'COUNT(T.id) AS transactions, ' +
  'COUNT(DISTINCT U.username) AS users ' +
  'FROM Users U, Transactions T, Accounts A ' +
  'WHERE U.accountId = A.id ' +
  'AND T.username = U.username ' +
  'AND U.accountId IN (' + ids.join(',') + ') ' +
  'GROUP BY U.username';
```